# How to "force"/warn the user to call dispose method of the object in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dispose

Some of my domain classes contain resources (such as `StreamController`) that need to be disposed. Consequently, I implement `dispose` method in such classes where I do my cleanup. There is no formal contract in dart (like `IDisposable` in C#) that would signify this (yes its trivial to implement something similar, I mean there is no *built in* facility/established style, afaik). So my `dispose` method is just any other method. User of the class might very well forget to call it someday.

Incidentally, I found out that same `StreamController` class (for example) somehow "forces" you to call its `close()` method, by giving a warning in IDE if the instance is encountered without corresponding `close()` call: `Close instances of "dart.core.Sink"`. I think this is implemented right into dart plugin for this particular class, and I wonder if there is any chance of giving such a warning to the users of my classes that contain `dispose`. Closest thing I've found is `@mustCallSuper` that helps with inheritance, but I'm looking for similar solution to the **users** of my classes.

Shortly, is there something similar to `@mustCallSuper` and `Sink.close()` IDE warning, that can be used to bring users' attention to the `dispose`-required objects?